# nbconvert failed: 'HTMLExporter' object has no attribute '_nb_metadata'

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I wanted to download HTML from Juypter Notebook. But I am getting an error when it perfroms.
The error is

> nbconvert failed: 'HTMLExporter' object has no attribute '_nb_metadata'.

I am sharing the screenshot of the error below.

[image]

How to fix it? Thanks.